# write the date in new line

Tags: java, servlets, cvs

TableNameI am trying to write set of row in to csv file and each ow should start with new line, I used println and \n nothing is printing in new line below is the code what i am trying to.

```
private void createBlankEmplDocForSubReports(HttpServletResponse response,
        List<HashMap<String, String>> results, String date, HttpServletRequest request )
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    SXSSFRow row = null;
    SXSSFCell cell = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement selectStmt = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
        if(request.getParameter("param1").equals("RED9")){
            selectStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * TableName");
        }else if(request.getParameter("param1").equals("RED921")){
            selectStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * TableName");
        }

        result = selectStmt.executeQuery();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in executing query during createBlankEmplDoc Report ::: " +e.getMessage());
    }

    try{
        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition:","filename=mycsvfilename.csv;");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        int rownum = 1;
        while(result.next()){
            out.println(result.getString("SSN"));
            out.println(',');
            out.println(result.getString("_NAME"));
            out.println(',');
            out.println(result.getString("SIDESRESPONSE"));
            out.println(',');
            out.println(result.getString("LAPSEDDAY"));
            out.println('\n');
            out.flush();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(out != null){
                    out.close();
                    out = null;
                }
                if (result != null) {
                    result.close();
                    result = null;
                }
                if (selectStmt != null) {
                    selectStmt.close();
                    selectStmt = null;
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                    conn = null;
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                DBUtil
                    .log("Exception from ExcelReportServlet class, Method -createNoEcmatsRegDoc "
                            + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i can able to compile and see the cvs file but everything in one line

Comment: Don't use `text/html` as the content type for CSV.  Try `text/csv` instead.

Comment: Hay stop using println() this will add newline after every entry.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach will be to Use Line seperator obtained by using 
`System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

If this file will get downloaded than there should be no problem but if this csv is shown on the browser's chrome it self then it is better to change the Content type to
`response.setContentType(text/csv;charset=UTF-8")`

And if the motto is just to show this on browser then user `<BR>` as suggested above.

For me `line.seperator` did the magic. Just add this line

`String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");`

And use this `lineSep` in place of '\n'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried it but i dint work-:(,Still i have the output with out line breaks

Comment: did you tried `String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");` because this totally worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

You are setting the content type as html,
so to break in a new line, it is necessary to use `<br/>` instead of `\n`

change the code `out.println('\n');` to `out.println('<br/>');`